# How can I get the siblings of a newly inserted inline?

Tags: slate.js

The following code doesn't work and I see the first inserted entity only when the code is running the second time:

```
editor.insertInline({
  key: 'XX',
  data: {},
  nodes: List([
    Text.create({
      'Hello World!',
    })
  ]),
  type: 'deletion',
})

const insertedDeletion = value.document.getInlinesByType('deletion').first()
```

Immediately after inserting the inline, `insertedDeletion` is *null*. Where exactly should I check for the existence of the inline? Is there a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigating, I found that I need to get the value directly from the editor instance:

```
const insertedDeletion = editor.value.document.getInlinesByType('deletion').first()
```